# React Native: How do I generate a box after user input with the text from user input?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

How do I generate a box after user input with the text from user input (selected, quantity, metric, day, month, year)?

I was also hoping to display and generate this box on another page in the Navigation stack but I am assuming I can do this by using the "props" keyword and initialising this function (AddFood) in the other page?

This is my code for the whole function (however the important parts are below):

```
// MANUALLY ADD FOOD
const AddFood = (props) => {

  // DROPDOWN MENU CONST
  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState("");

  // QUANTITY CONST
  const [quantity, setQuantity] = React.useState("");
  const [metric, setMetric] = React.useState("");

  // DATE CONST
  const [day, setDay] = React.useState("");
  const [month, setMonth] = React.useState("");
  const [year, setYear] = React.useState("");

  // DROPDOWN MENU DATA
  const data = [
    {key:'Test1',value:'Test1'},
    {key:'Test2',value:'Test2'},
    {key:'Test3',value:'Test3'},
  ]

  const metricData = [
    {key:'ml',value:'ml'},
    {key:'g',value:'g'},
    {key:'litres',value:'litres'},
  ]

  const dayData = [
    {key:'1',value:'01'},
  ]

  const monthData = [
    {key:'1',value:'01'},
  ]

  const yearData = [
    {key:'2023',value:'2023'},
  ]

  const onPressBack = () => {
    props.navigation.navigate('BarcodeOrManual');
  }

  // VALIDATION AND PASS DATA TO DATABASE
  const showAlert = () => {
    if (selected && quantity && metric && day && month && year) {

      Alert.alert (
        "Food entered successfully"
      );

      // Pass data here

    } else {

      Alert.alert (
        "Please fill in all the fields"
      );

    }
  }

  return (
    <View style={{ paddingHorizontal: 20, paddingVertical: 50, flex: 1 }}>

      {/* DROPDOWN MENU FOR FOOD */}
      <SelectList
        data={data}
        // onSelect={() => alert(selected)}
        // setSelected={setSelected} 
        setSelected={(val) => setSelected(val)}
        dropdownItemStyles={{marginHorizontal:10}}
        dropdownTextStyles={{color:'black'}}
        searchPlaceholder="Enter item"
        placeholder="Enter item"
        maxHeight={100}
      />

      {/* FOOD QUANTITY */}
      <Text>Quantity</Text>
      <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          onChangeText={setQuantity}
          value={quantity}
          keyboardType="numeric"
        />
        <SelectList
          data={metricData}
          // onSelect={() => alert(selected)}
          // setSelected={setSelected} 
          setSelected={(val) => setMetric(val)}
          dropdownItemStyles={{ marginHorizontal:10 }}
          dropdownTextStyles={{ color:'black' }}
          searchPlaceholder="(ml, g, etc.)"
          placeholder="Enter metric"
          maxHeight={100}
        />
      </View>

      {/* DATE */}
      <Text>Use by date</Text>
      <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
        <SelectList
          data={dayData}
          // onSelect={() => alert(selected)}
          // setSelected={setSelected} 
          setSelected={(val) => setDay(val)}
          dropdownItemStyles={{marginHorizontal:10}}
          dropdownTextStyles={{color:'black'}}
          placeholder=" "
          maxHeight={100}
        />
        <Text>DD /</Text>
        <SelectList
          data={monthData}
          // onSelect={() => alert(selected)}
          // setSelected={setSelected} 
          setSelected={(val) => setMonth(val)}
          dropdownItemStyles={{marginHorizontal:10}}
          dropdownTextStyles={{color:'black'}}
          placeholder=" "
          maxHeight={100}
        />
        <Text>MM /</Text>
        <SelectList
          data={yearData}
          // onSelect={() => alert(selected)}
          // setSelected={setSelected} 
          setSelected={(val) => setYear(val)}
          dropdownItemStyles={{marginHorizontal:10}}
          dropdownTextStyles={{color:'black'}}
          placeholder=" "
          maxHeight={100}
        />
        <Text>YYYY /</Text>
      </View>

      <Pressable onPress={showAlert} style={styles.button}>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 15, color: 'white' }}>Add Item</Text>
      </Pressable>

      <Pressable onPress={onPressBack} style={styles.button}>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 15, color: 'white' }}>BACK</Text>
      </Pressable>

    </View>
  )

  // VARIABLE STORES:
  // selected -> Food dropdown menu selection
  // quantity -> Quantity of food
  // metric -> The relevant metric for the quantity of food
  // day, month, year -> Use by date

}
```

The variables below is where the data I want to display is stored:

```
// DROPDOWN MENU CONST
  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState("");

  // QUANTITY CONST
  const [quantity, setQuantity] = React.useState("");
  const [metric, setMetric] = React.useState("");

  // DATE CONST
  const [day, setDay] = React.useState("");
  const [month, setMonth] = React.useState("");
  const [year, setYear] = React.useState("");
```

This is the code that is run when the button is pressed by the user:

```
// VALIDATION AND PASS DATA TO DATABASE
  const showAlert = () => {
    if (selected && quantity && metric && day && month && year) {

      Alert.alert (
        "Food entered successfully"
      );

      // Pass data here

    } else {

      Alert.alert (
        "Please fill in all the fields"
      );

    }
  }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using React Navigation, you can pass these variables as params when you navigate to the other page.

```js
  const { navigate } = useNavigation();
  navigate('otherScreen', { quantity, metric, day, month, year });
```

and in your other screen

```js
  const { params } = useRoute();
  console.log(params);
```

See https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/

Comment: Thank you very much! Where would the code for creating the box go? How could I create a function where every-time data is passed to this screen, a new piece of text (of the data) is displayed?

Comment: Use the params like any other variable - render a View with Text tags (or however you want it displayed)